# Facebook API not giving me complete list of members of Facebook groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying a very simple FQL :

```
SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid=<foo>
```

If my group has 3-4 members it works fine; but if it has thousands of members it returns me approx 33% of the members ! How can I get complete list

Comment: You can specify LIMIT, like `SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid=<foo> LIMIT 5000` But I guess that limit also has its limitations on how big that number is. If you wan't a consistent listing and crawl through all the results I would suggest the answer of Rahil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this too has some limitations. You can't get more than 500 group members using an API call. Your query will only return you a max of 500 random members from that group.

Workaround: You can use Facebook Graph API and make use of [pagination feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/). For example: To retrieve 400 group members, you can simply make a request using -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[Group ID]/members?limit=400&offset=0
```

This will return a list of 400 members of that group. You can then retrieve the next 400 members by increasing the offset to 400 and so on.

I tried [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=206743736105967/members?limit=400&offset=0) using the API explorer and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I used 400 limit, and every "next" page I used the last number (400, 800. 1200, ect') - and I still get to 5K. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Hatul: 5000 is the MAX limit for the results. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26665940/1382832

Comment: I think you need some kind of special permission from FB to do that. Not sure though. Read this: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Nice try ;) but its still not possible... :/